# Grails - Control the order of Database Columns

Tags: grails

How do I control the order of the Database Columns in my Domain Classes?

I use my domain objects to create the database tables but I would like the fields in the database to be in a certain order.

Is there a way I can control this order in my domain classes.

Comment: Why? There are so many more important things to worry about ...

Answer (score 3):

You can control the creation of the database schema by using the [Database migration plugin.](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) You can read more about how to use this plugin it in the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/index.html).